# Find if Keras and Tensorflow use the GPU

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I have installed tensorflow-gpu in my PC which runs Windows 10 and have two graphic cards:

[image]

I am trying to replicate the Tensorflow documentation:

[image]

However, I am not getting what is decribed in the documentation:

[image]

How can I find out if Tensorflow uses my gpus?  I believe I have followed all the set up instructions correctly but how can I verify it?

I understand that Tensorflow uses by default the available gpus.

### Updates

**@ Sharky:**

This is what I get when I follow your instructions, if I understood them well.  What I should infer and what I should next?

[image]

**@ Manoj**

This is what I get when I run the code from a python shell invoked from the command prompt:

[image]

What is the meaning and the implications of the message?

Comment: Valuable meta reading about the use of presenting text as images: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Answer (score 0):

Use `nvidia-smi` It can be found in `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI` if i'm not mistaken.

Change directory to where the nvidia-smi.exe is located, and run it from command prompt with `nvidia-smi` command. It also allows to monitor memory usage and gpu load in process with `nvidia-smi -l 1` where 1 is update freq in sec. You can find more options with `nvidia-smi -h`

Comment: That's right. What you see is memory usage and gpu-util in %. But that's for one gpu only. Your problem maybe in nccl library. Multi gpu is a tricky setup on windows

Comment: Also, one of your gpus is integrated if i got you right. paste `tf.logging.set_verbosity('INFO')` in the top of your program right after import tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

*However, I am not getting what is decribed in the documentation:*

I get the device logs when running the code snippet you provided on both CPU & GPU machines.

I notice that you're running it in some REPL or Notebook. Can you try saving the contents to a file and running it as a Python script?

Comment: Have you installed tensorflow-gpu? If not, do "pip uninstall tensorflow" and do "pip install tensorflow-gpu". Hope, CUDA is installed - https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#windows_setup.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install tensorflow with gpu support, usual `pip install tensorflow` is cpu only. [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) you can find gpu tensorflow install guide. After that when you run log_device_placement sample in terminal you should get info about gpu usage.